# Popover in bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm tring using bootstrap and I'm trying to implement popover effect on a link.
Here is the code for the link

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" title="Title of popover" data-content="some text to display">Link popover</a>
```

And here is the js code that I'm using on the bottom of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>  
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
```

Nothing happen I can just see the title in the normal tooltip window.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you added this line of code ?

```
$('.btn-danger').popover();
```

Comment: Yes but I realized that it was in a wrong position ... now everything is ok ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Load the bootstrap `docs.min.js` script.

```
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
```

I faced the same problem and for some reason the js required is written in this file.